# Java application kills remote Xvnc server

Tags: java, swing, fonts, vnc

I'll start this off by saying I'm relatively new to Java UI development. All machines involved are running RHEL6. Java is OpenJDK 1.7. I have an application (please excuse typos; I had to hand-copy this from an internetless environment):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class TestApp{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
    GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts();
    for (Font font: fonts){
     System.out.println(font.getFontName());
    }
    JTextArea text_pane = new JTextArea();
    System.out.println("Using " + text_pane.getFont().getFontName());
    text_pane.setText("HI");
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    j.add(text_pane);
    j.setSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    j.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
 }
}
```

As you can see, all this does is print all available font families, print the default font family, and display a little window with a bit of text. When I run this locally, it works fine. I have a remote machine running TurboVnc(turbo1.1) on display :99, started with the command

```
./Xvnc :99 -geometery 1000x1000 -ac
```

If I scp my app to the remote machine, export DISPLAY=:99.0, and run it, it works fine. However, if I try to run my application locally with the display exported to remotehost:99.0, the remote Xvnc server crashes with a double free or corruption. In the backtrace I see an AddGlyph call. My limited experience with X leads me to believe this is a font problem, i.e. the locally-running app is trying to use a font not available on the remote machine. The

```
System.out.println("Using " + text_pane.getFont().getFontName());
```

call does print out the same font name (Dialog.plain) when run on either machine, but I'm not sure if that actually means anything. Is there a way around this problem? Am I coming at this from the wrong angle entirely? I should note that xeyes and xterm run fine when exported from the local machine to the remote display, it's just my Java app that kills it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles onto this: the problem is that my version of Java is new enough that it enables xrender by default, but the Xvnc version on the remote server is old and doesn't support it. Launching the application with

```
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false
```

fixed the issue.